# "using these functions as an example" vs "using these functions as examples"

Tags: articles, singular-vs-plural, indefinite-article

> using these functions as an example

or

> using these functions as examples

Should it be **examples**, or **an example** is also okay?

The point is that, we need only to use one of them as an example.

Comment: Can you tell us whether you have learned what _singular_ and _plural_ mean in English? Is the noun phrase _these examples_ singular or plural?

Comment: If, as you say, you need to use *one of them as an example*, why not write just that?

Comment: @P.E.Dant  I can handle simple cases like 'The three computers are' and 'This car is', but not more complicated cases.

Comment: This really is a very simple case! See the comment above from @userr2684291 . Don't underestimate your ability to figure this out. Remember: a plural subject always takes a plural verb, and a singular subject always takes a singular verb.